# Directly scan document into pdf file

Tags: scanner, canon-pixma

I would like to scan a document, but I want to get pdf file directly.
I know that I can make jpg file and, using Acrobat, convert it to pdf.
I have win xp and printer is Canon MP280 Pixma.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that functionality would need to be provided by the scanner itself. Mine gives me the choice before I hit the 'go' button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canon should provide an application with the printer called MP Navigator EX that supports scanning to PDF. You can find the software from their site, under the Drivers and Software section